# i am trying to use importlib.import_module(package_name, class_name) but facing the below error

Tags: python, python-importlib

```
 Error occurred in import_library function ::: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alok.jha\Anaconda3\envs\myenv_dedupe\lib\DataManipulationLib\data_manipulation.py", line 2984, in import_local_libs
    interim_obj = importlib.import_module(package_name, class_name)
  File "C:\Users\alok.jha\Anaconda3\envs\myenv_dedupe\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
```

i am trying to use  importlib.import_module(package_name, class_name) but facing the below error

Comment: it is not able to take the two arguments (package_name, class_name) in import_module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing similar problem, and here is my solution.

Supposing I want to import class `Man` from the path `root.human`

```
import importlib

package = importlib.import_module('root.human')
```

Then I can call the `Man` class by `package.Man`.